# CakePHP json/xml error views

Tags: json, rest, cakephp

Im currently building a REST api using cakephp.
Basically when i send requests etc to for example add.json then it will take the input data and provide me with json data, likewise if i send it to add.xml it will give me an xml response.

However if something goes wrong when making this request such as a foreign key constraint,the response is a HTML page with the error inside. Is it possible to have json/xml views for errors?

Also in cakephp validation can a foreign key check be carried out as part of the validation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i managed to solve this problem.

First i changed my app/Config/core.php file to change the exception renderer.

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'RESTExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

Then after that i created my RESTExceptionRenderer.php in app/Lib/Error.
    App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

```
class RESTExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    protected function _outputMessage($template) {
        /*Check if we are an json or xml request*/
        if( $this->controller->request->params['ext'] === 'json' ){
            $this->controller->layout = null;
            echo parent::_outputMessage( "ajax/" . $template );
        } else if( $this->controller->request->params['ext'] === 'xml' ) {
            $this->controller->layout = null;
            echo parent::_outputMessage( "xml/" . $template );
        } else {
            parent::_outputMessage($template);
        }
    }

}
```

This way if some accesses index.json etc and an exception is thrown the error will be returned in json rather than html.